# Jquery: how to open external link in same window

Tags: jquery, external-url

I have the following code set up to open a URL in a the same Window but requires two clicks to open, any idea's why?

```
            $('button.more-details-link').on("click",function(){
                window.open(url, '_self')
            });
```

Comment: Did you mean to open the up the URL in the _same_ window? If not, then you want your target to be `_blank` instead of `_self`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a document ready function:
https://jsfiddle.net/z2b08x7t/

```
$(function(){ 
$('button.more-details-link').on("click",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var url = "google.com"
                window.open(url, '_self')
            });
    });
```

Or if you want to open it in a blank window:

```
 $(function(){ 
    $('button.more-details-link').on("click",function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var url = "google.com"
                    window.open(url, '_blank')
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('button.more-details-link').on('click', function(){
  window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings');
  return false;
});
});
```

or you can use

```
$(function(){
  $('yourselector').prop('target', '_blank');
});
```

For details regarding `window.open()` you can check [this](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/linking_famsupp_120.html) article